# Visual Studio 2010 - Very slow display update on MacPro running Win7/Bootcamp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, refresh, device-driver

I'm a .Net developer running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) on a 2010 MacPro (2.27Ghz/6GB RAM) using Bootcamp. Until about a month ago its been, imo, the ultimate dev workstation. However recently I've noticed that Visual Studio 2010 takes a very long time to redraw its windows. This is most noticeable when switching to it after its been in the foreground.

I don't get this problem with other Windows apps and am baffled because the machine has more than enough grunt to handle a few MDI'd windows yet grinds for up to five minutes sometimes when reactivating the VS environment - the screen update seems to slow everything down. My colleagues are using identical hardware and software but running Windows under Parallels on their Macs does not lead to this behaviour.

I'm getting desperate (and I've asked this same question at apple.stackexchange.com) - does anyone know why this might be happening and whether there's a fix ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Improving Performance by Changing the Visual Experience

You might have a problem with Hardware Acceleration in VS2010. I had an issue with rendering applications built using WPF because of this.

Give it a try:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/22/improving-performance-by-changing-the-visual-experience-vstipenv0017.aspx

And if that doesn't fix your issue, go to your video card settings (nvidia or amd) and do a "reset settings". Then try again.